# the probability of rolling a die

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a die with six faces numbered consecutively from 1 to 6. What is odd about it, is that the probability of rolling the face with number k on it is c*(q^k), where c is a constant, and q = 0.9.

What is the expected value of a roll of the die?

i could not get the constant c first got stuck here

Comment: You must have $\sum_{k=1}^6 cq^k=1$.

Comment: the expected value is that the sum of c*q^k with k=1,3,5?

Comment: I don't know what the probability of ROLLING the die is.... That's almost philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need that $\sum_1^6 cq^i = 1 \Rightarrow c = 1/(\sum_1^6 0.9^i)$. Then the expected value is $\sum i cq^i$.

Comment: the expected value is that the sum of c*q^k with k=1,3,5?

Comment: No, it's the sum over all possible values of the die roll. What definition of expected value are you using?